# Kendo Grid command: set text from response

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo Grid ([API](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid)) to display some data (go figure), but I'm trying to get a command button to display text from the returned json response. I can't find the command to do so, however. `this` doesn't seem to work and I'm not really sure what else it could be. `$("#grid")` references the whole grid, not individual rows, and the data isn't displayed in the grid anywhere. I've verified with Fiddler that the data is being sent back to the grid, I just don't know how to access it.

In case that's unclear: Kendo Grid displays data returned to it from a json response. I have data in that response that isn't directly bound to a column, but I want to use it to control the text displayed on a command button. How can this be accomplished, preferably without having to iterate through the whole grid afterward using jQuery?

Comment: You need to add an event for the onDataBound and look into the first row of the grid's dataSource to find your data.

Comment: @lrb I'm not quite sure how to accomplish that. Can you expand a little bit? I don't need my hand held, but a little more of a nudge would be great.

Comment: Please provide more information about the actual Data and how it's organized. There's a way to add columns to the grid and make them invisible for example; this is very useful in cases like having the id of the employee related to a certain row but keeping it hidden from users.

Comment: You are correct, In the binding you can add columns with a hidden attribute and still access them asusual. I don't know if you can access data returned to the grid that is not defined as a column in the data source, however, I think you can.